# Get peak and non-peak hours from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `peak_hours` table where a certain duration in hours
are defined as the 'peak hours'

```
id | start | end
1  | 05:00 | 09:00
2  | 12:00 | 15:00
3  | 17:00 | 22:00
```

I have a `jobs` table that keeps track of the start and end date of a job.

```
id |    started_at    |   completed_at
1  | 2019-05-07 04:00 | 2019-05-07 16:00
```

I'm trying to get the duration of which the job is in the peak, and non-peak hours

Expect output:

```
peak_hours_total | non_peak_hours_total
7                | 5
```

Comment: how you will assign peak hours and no peak hours?

Comment: The general idea would be to have a table that would have an hour table with 24 hours in it (obviously) join your Jobs table to it and get the hours split between started_at and completed_at.. then join to your peak hours table to determine if the hour from the split falls in that range and count accordingly!

Comment: @DaleBurrell I haven't started anything yet, this is a new problem for me, I'm still planning on how to approach this at the moment.

Will get update POST with code as I go a long.

I agree, it's not a code writing service, but leaving hints or guidance wouldn't hurt

Comment: Thats not how SO is intended to work - there are other communities for that.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I disagree. No code in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

If you can't contribute anything, you're welcome to ignore this post. I really don't have the time for trolls

Comment: Its not my opinion, its the sites guidelines. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348591/how-to-flag-close-as-not-a-code-writing-service

Comment: @DaleBurrell Ah, point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Harry mentioned in the comments, one way of doing this is to expand single row with the date ranges into multiple rows, each representing a value at the desired level of granularity (hour, minute, etc.). This is all done because SQL Server is not really efficient when working with ranges and also, transaction data may extend over multiple days.

Following example expands data into minute level granularity and gives desired result. Keep in mind that I spent no time in trying to optimize the code, so there is definitely room for improvement:

```sql
-- Input
;with PeakHours as (
    select 1 as id, '05:00' as [start], '09:00' as [end]
    union all
    select 2 as id, '12:00' as [start], '15:00' as [end]
    union all
    select 3 as id, '17:00' as [start], '22:00' as [end]
)
, data as (
    select 1 as id, '2019-05-07 04:00' as started_at, '2019-05-07 16:00' as completed_at
)
-- Convert start and end to UNIX to be able to get ranges
, data2 as (
    select *
        ,DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', started_at) as started_at_unix
        ,DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', completed_at) as completed_at_unix
    from data
)
-- Find min start and max end to cover whole possible range
, data3 as (
    select min(started_at_unix) as min_started_at_unix, max(completed_at_unix) as max_completed_at_unix
    from data2
)
-- expand data using Tally table technique
,lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) 
,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) 
,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) 
,lv4 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b) 
,lv5 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv4 a CROSS JOIN lv4 b) 
,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv5)
, data_expanded as (
    SELECT TOP (select (max_completed_at_unix - min_started_at_unix) / 60 from data3) (n - 1) * 60 + d3.min_started_at_unix as unix_timestamp_min
    from Tally as t
    cross apply data3 as d3
)
-- Aggregate
select
     1.0 * sum(case when ph.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) / 60 as peak_hours_total 
    ,1.0 * sum(case when ph.id is null then 1 else 0 end) / 60 as non_peak_hours_total
from data_expanded as de
inner join data2 as d2
    on de.unix_timestamp_min between d2.started_at_unix and d2.completed_at_unix
left join PeakHours as ph
    on cast(dateadd(s, de.unix_timestamp_min, '1970-01-01') as time(0)) between ph.[start] and dateadd(SECOND, -1, cast(ph.[end] as time(0)))
```